# How to return an object templated with lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
class BaseTask {
  // Implementation here
};

class BaseSubtask {
  BaseTask *_pTask;
public:
  explicit BaseSubtask(BaseTask *pTask) : _pTask(pTask) { }
  virtual void Run() = 0;
  // The rest of implementation here.
};

template<typename taFunc> class LambdaSubtask {
  taFunc _f;
public:
  explicit LambdaSubtask(BaseTask *pTask, taFunc&& f)
  : BaseSubtask(pTask), _f(std::forward<taFunc>(f))
  { }
  LambdaSubtask(const LambdaSubtask&) = delete;
  LambdaSubtask& operator=(const LambdaSubtask&) = delete;
  LambdaSubtask(LambdaSubtask&&) = delete;
  LambdaSubtask& operator=(LambdaSubtask&&) = delete;
  virtual void Run() override final { _f(); }
  // The rest of implementation here
};
```

Because I cannot declare a `LambdaSubtask` object without specifying its template type argument, and I cannot specify its template type argument because it's a lambda, I try to implement a factory method:

```
template<typename taFunc> inline LambdaSubtask<taFunc>
MakeLambdaSubtask(BaseTask *pTask, taFunc&& f) {
  return { pTask, std::forward<taFunc>(f) };
}
```

Unfortunately this gives a compilation error:

> copy-list-initialization of `LambdaSubtask<lambda_...>` cannot use an explicit constructor

With a proper factory method I could get a `LambdaSubtask` object as follows:

```
BaseTask task; // Initialization of the task is skipped in the example
auto&& lst = MakeLambdaSubtask(&task, [/* Capture here*/]() {
  // Implementation here
});
```

So basically I want a local variable object of `LambdaSubtask` type, with template type being a lambda. I want to avoid extra copying of anything. Surely I want to avoid `std::function` as my benchmarks show it's extremely slow.

Do you know how to implement a proper factory method or get local variable object of `LambdaSubtask` type in another way?

My compiler is MSVC++2017 with toolset v141 , so C++11/14/17 is partially supported.

Comment: `return LambdaSubtask<taFunc>{ pTask, std::forward<taFunc>(f) };`, although you probably want `LambdaSubtask<std::decay_t<taFunc>>`

Comment: @Justin, AFAIK, this would involve copy/move constructor of `LambdaSubtask`. The move of `LambdaSubtask` itself could be made efficient, but I'm not sure how efficient would be the move of lambda that it has as a member variable.

Comment: If you have some function type `F`, either `taFunc` will be `F` or some sort of `F&` depending on whether you called `MakeLambdaSubtask` with an rvalue or lvalue. If it was a `F&`, now your `LambdaSubtask` is immovable, unassignable, etc. That could be what you want, but it is unexpected. I tend to prefer avoiding unexpected behavior, but it's up to you

Comment: I wonder if `decltype` can solve problem of instancing the template.. but yeah, you can't construct object implicitly, because you said so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you're trying to do this:

```
struct X {
    explicit X(int ) { }
};

X foo() { return {4}; }
```

That doesn't work because the `X` constructor is `explicit` and you're doing copy-list-initialization. The workaround is just to explicitly construct:

```
X foo() { return X{4}; }
//              ^^^
```

Note that in C++17, this does not incur a copy or move. Prior to C++14, this wouldn't incur a copy or move either but the move would still have to be well-formed.

The other alternative would be to remove the `explicit` mark from your constructor, which is what is preventing you from returning a braced-init-list.

---

As a side-note, be careful about:

```
template<typename taFunc>
LambdaSubtask<taFunc> MakeLambdaSubtask(BaseTask *pTask, taFunc&& f) { ... }
```

If you're passed in an lvalue function, you're going to keep a reference to it - so that's an extra lifetime you have to worry about. For this reason, it's common to instead return `LambdaSubtask<std::decay_t<taFunc>>`. This ensures that the Subtask has a valid function for its lifetime.

Comment: No, an important restriction is missing: I'm trying to avoid extra copy/move constructor invocations. AFAIK, the function in your example violates that restriction.

Comment: @SergeRogatch In C++17, there is no copy/move in the example.

Comment: MSVC++2017 toolset v141 (the latest) doesn't seem to support this piece of C++17...

Comment: @SergeRogatch That is correct. C++17's copy elision is not currently supported in Visual C++

Answer (score 3):

You did it unto yourself by declaring your lambda constructor explicit. Remove explicit and your code should compile.

Remember, uniform list initialization doesn't work with explicit constructors.

Comment: What a great hit! So surprising it is that simple... Indeed, the code compiles after removing `explicit` .